# django postgresql OperationalError: index row size xxx exceeds maximum yyy

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to learn a bit of django and trying to insert some values in a database (using model forms), but this seems failing citing:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: index row size 3008 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "appname_mymodel_ggg_like"
```

My models are quite simple and look like so:

```
class myModel(TimeStampedModel):

    fff =  models.URLField(db_index=False, blank=False,primary_key=False) 
    ggg = models.TextField(db_index=False, blank=False,primary_key=False)
    mj = models.BooleanField(db_index=False, blank=False, primary_key=False,  default=False) # req field

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.fff
```

Does this mean that the string is long (yes it is, but not a 1MB string or anything)? This is the reason I was using text field.. but this does not seem to help.

Any hints would be appreciated..

Comment: are you sure that this is model that is created in the DB, it looks like you have different model in Django and different in database - remove model from the database and recreate it using django (e.g. by migrating app backwards and then forwards)

Comment: Cross site duplicate of: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94205/unique-constraint-on-large-varchars-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

If anyone gets here through the error message, for me it was this [unresolved bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14904).

Basically a django TextField can be large in size, but if we make it unique as well, the uniqueness check can break.

A suggested "fix" was using the md5 hash for the uniqueness check.

Comment: True, I did not see that. The error message matches the title and led me here though, so I hope this post can save someone some time researching regardless.

Comment: I've had this error on a non-unique indexed `TextField` as well.